# how to centre and fix size of a pie chart while offset is added from react chartjs 2?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2

I need to center the pie chart into a component/div and also reduce the size of the chart to fix the cutting out in the ends.

[image]

Its cuts-off at bottom and sides.

**Code:**

```
export const data = {
  labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "# of Votes",
      data: [13,1],
      backgroundColor: [
        "rgba(235, 159, 12,0.7)",
        "rgba(235, 159, 12, 1)",
      ],
      borderColor: [
        "rgba(235, 159, 12, 0.7)",
        "rgba(235, 159, 12, 1)",
      ],
      borderWidth: 1,
      offset:20
    },
  ],
};

export const options = {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: true,
    plugins: {
      title: {
        display: false,
      },
      legend:{
          display:false
      },
    },
  };

function MiniChart() {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col w-[150px] lg:w-[200px]">
      <p className="text-center text-md lg:text-lg">Unicorn Startups</p>
      <div className="bg-red-100 w-[150px] h-[150px] lg:w-[200px] lg:h-[200px]">
        <Pie data={data} options={options}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I made some more tests and find out seems a Chart.js itself bug (when the small pieces of the pie are on the top and the offset is active)...  

Look again my stackblitz (in particular the dataset `data`) https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-fabpct?file=App.tsx,package.json,index.tsx

If you try to switch the data (from my comments) you'll notice that sometime works fine, some other crop the chart (when the big piece is on the bottom).

I suggest you to open an issue to the Chart.js repo (https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues)

Comment: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/other-charts/pie.html
If you play with the dataset in this live example, you will see that is reproducible also on their own website  (`DATA_COUNT=2` and by adding the `offset: 20` in the setup tab for example)

Comment: Since I use Chart.js in some projects and have not seen any issues regarding this bug, I have opened one myself. Those interested can follow the updates directly on the [Issue](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/10465) on Github 

Comment: Here's a [workaround](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/10465#issuecomment-1173953554) to the problem (using layout padding option; but you will lose the perfect fit of the chart with the parent container). Thanks to `@stockiNail` on Github.

Answer (score 0):

you can reduce the size of the chart without affecting its ratio by setting the responsive to false.
so change
`responsive: true`
to
`responsive: false`

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug.

Has been fixed in Chart.Js `^4.0.0`.

Here's the solved [Issue on Github](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/10469).

You can check the fix from the [website, in the Pie example](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/other-charts/pie.html) by acting on the dataset config values, adding some offset.